# Extend Activity changing only the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to extend an existing activity changing only its layout (eg. colors)?

Because i'm using a shared library and i shouldn't modify the activity since others are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to put that new Activity in the manifest and then make sure the intent resolution goes to your child class. Your not just going to be able to extend the activity and have it called without fixing this (at least I don't think so).

You can also just set the background color in java or xml.

Comment: i managed to change colors of the background and buttons by java code.
But if i want to really change the layout (add decorations, add buttons/functionalities, change gravity ecc) do i have to do everything by java code or there is the possibility to use a different xml without losing all the code in the original constructor? Anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: I don't believe that you can inherit from two different XML files (at least I haven't seen it). However, what I would recommend is that you create a style in XML and then you can apply that to you view via one line of java. That way your not modifying the lib's XML and you can still declare your attributes in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.It is possible , Just use the word  `extends`.

If u have 2 activity
Activity1 and 2nd Activity2.
U can use `Activity2 extends Activity1`
Then u can use the property of `Activity1.`

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing.

Comment: i know about extends, the problem is that i would like to change the layout, but the super.onCreate() generates its own layout... can i just change colors and size of the elements without redeclaring them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can extend it and by overriding onCreate method and calling setContentView method in it by your custom layout you'll be changing it's layout.

Comment: Is there a way of saving the code in the original onCreate() so that if the parent class is changed also mine is changing (i would like that the ONLY difference would be the graphics)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could be accomplished like this:

Your common activity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
 ..
 ..
}
```

Your specific activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends BaseActivity {
 ..
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //call the base class constructor FIRST 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); //then change the layout
     }
}
```

Comment: this was my idea, but when i call setContentView it erases all the stuff the super.onCreate() generated

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can extend your activity, here is a demo:

```
    package com.test.intentdemo; 

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.RelativeLayout; 

public class intentDemo extends Activity { 
    public static final String TAG="MyActivity"; 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        RelativeLayout lLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.layout.the_id); 
        lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
    } 
} 

            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG,0)) 
            { 
                Log.e(TAG,"ERROR BEFORE"); 
                Log.i(TAG,"INFO BEFORE"); 
                Log.d(TAG,"DEBUG BEFORE"); 

                    lLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); 
                    //SystemClock.sleep(2000); 
                    try 
                    { 
                    Thread.currentThread(); 
                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    { 
                    //e.message(); 
                    } 


                Log.e(TAG,"ERROR AFTER"); 
                Log.i(TAG,"INFO AFTER"); 
                Log.d(TAG,"DEBUG AFTER"); 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

Hope this helps :)